# How to replaceAll "" with " " without touching a specific number?

Tags: java

This may look like a duplicate question but I really couldn't find an answer in those. After searching I learnt about regex and matcher but I couldn't come up with a solution. If you could help me I would really appreciate it.

In Java I want to `replaceAll` `""` with `" "` in a string but only number 10 shouldn't be touched. So I don't want `10` to be like `1 0`

Here is a String: `String x = "123456789"`

If I use this: `x.replaceAll(".(?=.)", "$0 ")`

I get: `"1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9"`

But if string was: `x = "12345678910"` How could I get: `"1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10"`
and it could be like: `x = {123104}` And once again I need `{1 2 3 10 4}`

Thank you for checking...

Comment: `"12345678910".replaceAll("", " ").replaceAll("1 0", "10")` ?

Comment: @alfasin Thank you so much! I've been thinking a way to figure this out for hours :D

Comment: Always look for the simplest possible solution (KISS principle ;) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it to work with other numbers than 10:

```
String x = "12345678910";
x = x.replaceAll(".(?!0)", "$0 ");
System.out.println(x);
```

Output:

> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

---

```
String x = "123456789101001230";
x = x.replaceAll(".(?!0)", "$0 ");
System.out.println(x);
```

Output:

> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 100 1 2 30

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this was the exact code I was using though it didn't work. This way makes 10 like 1 0.

Comment: @JohnMerih No, it is not the same code. I've replaced the `=` in `(?=0)` with a `!`. [Here](http://ideone.com/Tx3c5o) is a link to a working example.

Comment: My mistake you are right. Thumbs up. Thank you once again!